# JPA: java.lang.StackOverflowError on adding toString method in entity classes

Tags: hibernate, stack-overflow, jpql, tostring, jpa-2.1

Everything worked fine until I added `toSting()` in my entity classes.

After which I start getting the following error in runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at entity.Guide.toString(Guide.java:51)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at entity.Student.toString(Student.java:45)
        ...
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;    

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="teacher", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>(); 

    public Teacher() {}
    public Teacher(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }       
    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
        student.setTeacher(this);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Teacher[id=" + id + ", name=" + name
                + ", students=" + students + "]";
    }

}
```

---

```
public class SnafuClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("snafu");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction txn = em.getTransaction();

                try {
                    txn.begin();

                    Query query = em.createQuery("select teacher from Teacher teacher");
                    List<Teacher> teachers = query.getResultList();

                    for (Teacher teacher: teachers) {
                System.out.println(teacher);
            }


                    txn.commit();
                }   catch(Exception e) {
                    if(txn != null) { txn.rollback(); }
                    e.printStackTrace();
             }  finally {
                    if(em != null) { em.close(); }
                }

    }
}
```

---

**EDIT: Code for Student entity added**

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name="teacher_id")
    private Teacher teacher;

    public Student() {}
    public Student(String name, Teacher teacher) {
        this.name = name;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }
    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + 
                + ", name=" + name + ", teacher=" + teacher + "]";
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Updated based on the addition of the Student class

According to the stack trace, your problem is associated with the `Student.toString()`, so here's what is happening:

In `Teacher.toString()`, you are implicitly calling the `Student.toString()` by placing the `students` member within a `String` concatenation statement: `+ students +`. Within `Student.toString()` the code does something similar, by including the `teacher` member within a `String` concatenation statement.

This means that calling either `Teacher.toString()` or `Student.toString()` will end up causing a never-ending loop where: `Teacher.toString()` implicitly calls `Student.toString()`, which in turn implicitly calls `Teacher.toString()`, which in turn calls `Student.toString()`, which in turn calls...

The 2 `.toString()` implementations keep calling back and forth, back and forth, back and forth, in a never-ending loop, which eventually overflows the stack and results in a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

To correct the problem, you should remove the implicit references to the `.toString()` methods of the entities. As a replacement, you could have `Teacher.toString()` simply output the `length()` of the `students` collection and maybe include a list of the `Student` name(s). And in the `Student.toString()`, simply include the `Teacher.name` member.

Comment: Edited the post by added the code for `Student` entity at the bottom.

Comment: Just updated the `toString` method in the `Guide` entity to this  `public String toString() { return "Guide [id=" + id + ", staffId=" + staffId + ", name=" + name + ", salary=" + salary + ", students.size()=" + students.size() + "]"; }`. It solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @skip - I have updated my answer based on your addition of the `Student` class. My original guess was correct and my answer should help you get the problem corrected.

Answer (score 4):

You must exclude the redundant parameter from the toString() method.

- In Java using [Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56263668/5279996) with `@ToString.Exclude`
- In Kotlin using a [custom annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63108202/5279996) with `@ExcludeToString`

GL

Answer (score 1):

Entity Class Teacher have `toString()` problem:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;    

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="teacher", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>(); 

public Teacher() {}
public Teacher(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}       
public void addStudent(Student student) {
    students.add(student);
    student.setTeacher(this);
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Teacher[id=" + id + ", name=" + name
            + "]";
}

}
```