# Property include/exclude on Kotlin data classes

Tags: kotlin, reflection, annotations, data-class

Suppose I only want one or two fields to be included in the generated equals and hashCode implementations (or perhaps exclude one or more fields).  For a simple class, e.g.:

```
data class Person(val id: String, val name: String)
```

Groovy has this:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = 'id')
```

Lombok has this:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
```

What is the idiomatic way of doing this in Kotlin?

#### My approach so far

```
data class Person(val id: String) {
   // at least we can guarantee it is present at access time
   var name: String by Delegates.notNull()

   constructor(id: String, name: String): this(id) {
      this.name = name
   }
}
```

Just feels wrong though... I don't really want `name` to be mutable, and the extra constructor definition is ugly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've used this approach.

```
data class Person(val id: String, val name: String) {
   override fun equals(other: Person) = EssentialData(this) == EssentialData(other)
   override fun hashCode() = EssentialData(this).hashCode()
   override fun toString() = EssentialData(this).toString().replaceFirst("EssentialData", "Person")
}

private data class EssentialData(val id: String) {
   constructor(person: Person) : this(id = person.id) 
}
```

Comment: equals should override "Any?"

Comment: Do you mean other should be Any? ? If so, maybe, but this way the compiler should use the Any.equals(any) when it knows that the rhs is not a Person. I suppose that there is an edge case where you have lost the type of the rhs...

Comment: This looks kind of cumbersome. Is this still the best solution up to date?

Comment: Improvent for the ```equals``` fun :

```override fun equals(other: Any?):Boolean{ 
      if(other != Person) return false
      return EssentialData(this) == EssentialData(other)
}
```

Comment: a more idiomatic way to write @dstibbe's improvement is: `override fun equals(other: Any?) = other is Person && EssentialData(this) == EssentialData(other)`

Comment: Nice improvement @KristopherNoronha.

Answer (score 14):

This approach may be suitable for property exclusion:

```
class SkipProperty<T>(val property: T) {
  override fun equals(other: Any?) = true
  override fun hashCode() = 0
}
```

`SkipProperty.equals` simply returns true, which causes the embeded `property` to be skipped in `equals` of parent object.

```
data class Person(
    val id: String, 
    val name: SkipProperty<String>
)
```

Comment: It's creative, so +1 for that, but this is not a solution I would employ. You have the extra `.property` on any access to a field whose lack of participation in the equals/hashCode of its containing class is frankly solely an implementation detail of that class. You could of course override `get()/set()` on that property to do this automatically, but ooof. Heavy for such a requirement.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just want to share my attempt.

Comment: Thank goodness Kotlin came along and saved us from the complexity of Java.

Answer (score 11):

This builds on @bashor's approach and uses a private primary and a public secondary constructor. Sadly the property to be ignored for equals cannot be a val, but one can hide the setter, so the result is equivalent from an external perspective.

```
data class ExampleDataClass private constructor(val important: String) {
  var notSoImportant: String = ""
    private set

  constructor(important: String, notSoImportant: String) : this(important) {
    this.notSoImportant = notSoImportant
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the recommended approach these days. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#properties-declared-in-the-class-body

Answer (score 7):

I also don't know "the idomatic way" in Kotlin (1.1) to do this...

I ended up overriding `equals` and `hashCode`:

```
data class Person(val id: String,
                  val name: String) {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other?.javaClass != javaClass) return false

        other as Person

        if (id != other.id) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return id.hashCode()
    }
}
```

Isn't there a "better" way?

Comment: I think my solution is also not perfect, but has some benefits. Take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a somewhat creative approach:

```
data class IncludedArgs(val args: Array<out Any>)

fun includedArgs(vararg args: Any) = IncludedArgs(args)


abstract class Base {
    abstract val included : IncludedArgs

    override fun equals(other: Any?) = when {
        this identityEquals other -> true
        other is Base -> included == other.included
        else -> false
    }

    override fun hashCode() = included.hashCode()

    override fun toString() = included.toString()
}

class Foo(val a: String, val b : String) : Base() {
    override val included = includedArgs(a)
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val foo1 = Foo("a", "b")
    val foo2 = Foo("a", "B")

    println(foo1 == foo2) //prints "true"
    println(foo1)         //prints "IncludedArgs(args=[a])"
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution!  I personally wouldn't trade a few lines of boilerplate assignment, e.g. `val name: String = name`  in @bashor's example for inheritance from a `Base` class that serves to make up for a missing language feature.

Comment: I agree, my solution is not very elegant. I just hacked it together for the fun of it and decided to share.

Answer (score 2):

**Reusable solution:** to have an easy way to select which fields to include in `equals()` and `hashCode()`, I wrote a little helper called "stem" (essential core data, relevant for equality).

Usage is straightforward, and the resulting code very small:

```
class Person(val id: String, val name: String) {
    private val stem = Stem(this, { id })

    override fun equals(other: Any?) = stem.eq(other)
    override fun hashCode() = stem.hc()
}
```

It's possible to trade off the backing field stored in the class with extra computation on-the-fly:

```
    private val stem get() = Stem(this, { id })
```

Since `Stem` takes any function, you are free to specify how the equality is computed. For more than one field to consider, just add one lambda expression per field (varargs):

```
    private val stem = Stem(this, { id }, { name })
```

---

**Implementation:**

```
class Stem<T : Any>(
        private val thisObj: T,
        private vararg val properties: T.() -> Any?
) {     
    fun eq(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (thisObj === other)
            return true

        if (thisObj.javaClass != other?.javaClass)
            return false

        // cast is safe, because this is T and other's class was checked for equality with T
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") 
        other as T

        return properties.all { thisObj.it() == other.it() }
    }

    fun hc(): Int {
        // Fast implementation without collection copies, based on java.util.Arrays.hashCode()
        var result = 1

        for (element in properties) {
            val value = thisObj.element()
            result = 31 * result + (value?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        }

        return result
    }

    @Deprecated("Not accessible; use eq()", ReplaceWith("this.eq(other)"), DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean = 
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Stem.equals() not supported; call eq() instead")

    @Deprecated("Not accessible; use hc()", ReplaceWith("this.hc(other)"), DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
    override fun hashCode(): Int = 
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Stem.hashCode() not supported; call hc() instead")
}
```

In case you're wondering about the last two methods, their presence makes the following erroneous code fail at compile time:

```
override fun equals(other: Any?) = stem.equals(other)
override fun hashCode() = stem.hashCode()
```

The exception is merely a fallback if those methods are invoked implicitly or through reflection; can be argued if it's necessary.

Of course, the `Stem` class could be further extended to include automatic generation of `toString()` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler, faster, look at there, or into the Kotlin documentation.
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/ignoring-certain-properties-when-generating-equals-hashcode-etc/2715/2
Only fields inside the primary constructor are taken into account to build automatic access methods like equals and so on. Do keep the meaningless ones outside.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another hacky approach if you **don't want to touch the data class**.
You can reuse the entire `equals()` from data classes while excluding some fields.
Just `copy()` the classes with fixed values for excluded fields:

```
data class Person(val id: String,
                  val name: String)
fun main() {
    val person1 = Person("1", "John")
    val person2 = Person("2", "John")
    println("Full equals: ${person1 == person2}")
    println("equals without id: ${person1.copy(id = "") == person2.copy(id = "")}")
   
}
```

Output:

```
Full equals: false
equals without id: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following generic approach for the implementation of equals/hashcode. The code below should have no performance impact because of the use of inlining and kotlin value classes:

```
@file:Suppress("EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURE_WARNING")

package org.beatkit.common

import kotlin.jvm.JvmInline

@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
@JvmInline
value class HashCode(val value: Int = 0) {
    inline fun combineHash(hash: Int): HashCode = HashCode(31 * value + hash)
    inline fun combine(obj: Any?): HashCode = combineHash(obj.hashCode())
}

@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
@JvmInline
value class Equals(val value: Boolean = true) {
    inline fun combineEquals(equalsImpl: () -> Boolean): Equals = if (!value) this else Equals(equalsImpl())
    inline fun <A : Any> combine(lhs: A?, rhs: A?): Equals = combineEquals { lhs == rhs }
}

@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
object Objects {
    inline fun hashCode(builder: HashCode.() -> HashCode): Int = builder(HashCode()).value

    inline fun hashCode(vararg objects: Any?): Int = hashCode {
        var hash = this
        objects.forEach {
            hash = hash.combine(it)
        }
        hash
    }

    inline fun hashCode(vararg hashes: Int): Int = hashCode {
        var hash = this
        hashes.forEach {
            hash = hash.combineHash(it)
        }
        hash
    }

    inline fun <T : Any> equals(
        lhs: T,
        rhs: Any?,
        allowSubclasses: Boolean = false,
        builder: Equals.(T, T) -> Equals
    ): Boolean {
        if (rhs == null) return false
        if (lhs === rhs) return true
        if (allowSubclasses) {
            if (!lhs::class.isInstance(rhs)) return false
        } else {
            if (lhs::class != rhs::class) return false
        }
        @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
        return builder(Equals(), lhs, rhs as T).value
    }
}
```

With this in place, you can easily implement/override any equals/hashcode implementation in a uniform way:

```
data class Foo(val title: String, val bytes: ByteArray, val ignore: Long) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return Objects.equals(this, other) { lhs, rhs ->
            this.combine(lhs.title, rhs.title)
                .combineEquals { lhs.bytes contentEquals rhs.bytes }
            // ignore the third field for equals
        }
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return Objects.hashCode(title, bytes) // ignore the third field for hashcode
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an [annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/annotations.html) that represents the exclusion of the property as `@ExcludeToString` or with `@ToString(Type.EXCLUDE)` parameters by defining enum.

And then using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44653046/5279996) format the value of the `getToString()`.

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ExcludeToString

data class Test(
        var a: String = "Test A",
        @ExcludeToString var b: String = "Test B"
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return ExcludeToStringUtils.getToString(this)
    }
}

object ExcludeToStringUtils {

    fun getToString(obj: Any): String {
        val toString = LinkedList<String>()
        getFieldsNotExludeToString(obj).forEach { prop ->
            prop.isAccessible = true
            toString += "${prop.name}=" + prop.get(obj)?.toString()?.trim()
        }
        return "${obj.javaClass.simpleName}=[${toString.joinToString(", ")}]"
    }

    private fun getFieldsNotExludeToString(obj: Any): List<Field> {
        val declaredFields = obj::class.java.declaredFields
        return declaredFields.filterNot { field ->
            isFieldWithExludeToString(field)
        }
    }

    private fun isFieldWithExludeToString(field: Field): Boolean {
        field.annotations.forEach {
            if (it.annotationClass == ExcludeToString::class) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

GL

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Coronel-B/88ac762bee486eb83ded694a055da6d7)