# Shorthand syntax for generating toString() method in Kotlin (for non-data classes)

Tags: java, kotlin, lombok

In Kotlin, it's possible to generate `toString()` method for data classes:

```
data class Foo(...)
```

But there are some limitations on using data classes, plus Kotlin compiler generates additional methods, which I don't want to have in my code.

In Java, you can generate `toString()` method with Lombok just by adding one line of code with `@ToString` annotation:

```
@ToString
public class Foo {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, Lombok doesn't work with Kotlin, so I have to implement `toString()` method manually each time:

```
class Foo {
    ...
    override fun toString(): String {
        // bunch of code here
    }
}
```

Is there any shorthand syntax for this in Kotlin or maybe some third-party solution?

Comment: I don't know such solutions(like Lombok @toString), perhaps you can implement an abstract class and override toString once using reflection to make it general, but not looks like nice idea.
or try to ask in Kotlin slack channel, there are lots of JB guys, they know it better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin - generate toString() for a non-data class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862207/kotlin-generate-tostring-for-a-non-data-class)

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want the additional methods, or is it just to reduce the amount of methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), you can use the [ToStringBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) which allows this:

```
override fun toString() = ToStringBuilder(this)
    .append("field1", field1)
    .append("field2", field2)
    .toString()
```

or, at the cost of some speed, a shorter reflective solution:

```
override fun toString() = ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this)
```

The format can be changed by passing a different [`ToStringStyle`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringStyle.html) to the builder.

I don't believe Kotlin itself has any support for this.