# Why is this toString() method causing StackOverFlowError?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have understood from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593893/why-im-getting-stackoverflowerror) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973347/jpa-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-on-adding-tostring-method-in-entity-classes#)
answer, the possible scenarios where your code could get into an infinite loop resulting into stackOverFlowError but I don't understand how the same scenario is getting replicated here,

```
public class A {
  private B b = new B();
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "b "+b;
  }
}

public class B {
  private A a = new A();
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "";
  }
}

public class StackoverflowErrorTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     A a = new A();
     System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

This code is generating below stack trace:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at stackoverflowerror.B.<init>(B.java:5)
at stackoverflowerror.A.<init>(A.java:5)
.
.
.
```

As per my understanding, When I am printing object 'a' in the main method, it will invoke the toString method of A class, in that method I am returning the object of B class which would implicitly call the toString method of B class. Now, in the toString method of B class, all I am returning is an empty string. Then how and where is the scope of infinite loop coming into picture here. Please explain.

Comment: Feel free to comment both ```toString()``` methods, just to see if they have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: I couldn't find a Stack Overflow duplicate.  But here is a Quora dupe: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-following-Java-program-throw-a-stack-overflow-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It enters the endless cycle of events. The method `toString()` is innocent in this case:

1. The method `main` creates an instance of the class `A`
2. The class `A` creates an instance of the class `B` upon initialization
3. The class `B` creates an instance of the class `A` upon initialization
4. Go to the step `2`

The local variables are allocated on the stack and the [`StackOverflowError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) is a result of a bad recursive call.

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

Recommended solution, remove the reference to the class `A` in the class `B` because it's unused:

```
public class B {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is not with `toString`, but with `private B b = new B();` and `private A a = new A();`.

You are creating A which creates B which creates A which creates B and so on

And stacktrace says exact same thing: `B.<init>` means initializer, not `toString`. It also points you to the lines throwing exception: `B.java:5` and `A.java:5`

Live code: https://ideone.com/H8wwOR

If you really need to hold `A` in `B` and `B` in `A` you could either pass them using constructor parameters or via setter methods:

```
class A {
    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class B {
    private A a;

    public A getA() {
        return this.a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

And then use them like:

```
B b = new B();
A a = new A(b);
b.setA(a);
```

This is a simplified example so you can get idea. In large applications you might want to add builders, field / constructor parameters injection or factories if needed.

Answer (score 2):

When in your main you call `A a = new A();` , the code will call the constructor of A, which will call `private B b = new B();` , which will call `private A a = new A();` and so on for infinite loop :)

The problem is not related to `toString()` at all

Answer (score 0):

Every `A` contains a new `B` in its `b` field. And every `B` contains a new `A` in its `a` field.

Creating a new `A` automatically creates a new `B`, and creating *that* automatically creates another new `A`, and another new `B`, and so on until the stack overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Your A contains a B which contains an A which contains a B which contains an A which contains a B which contains an A which contains a B which contains an A which contains a B which contains an A which contains a B ....

Your A in B isn't used so you can remove it.

Note: the stack trace shows the problem is in construction ie () and nothing to do with your toString();

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, whenever you are creating an object of class A (or B) it also creates a new object of class B(or A in case of B) whenever instantiated. Now this is a never ending cycle as whenever a new object is created of either class A or B, again a new object of another class is created as well resulting in an infinite cycle of object creation. Therefore, throwing the java.lang.StackOverflowError exception.